# "No completions available" on var_

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

i have againg a problem with completition. now i can't get any suggestion. Sure i can type var_dump, but it is  more comfortable with autocompletion.

I'm using Eclipse PHP Ide 3.5 with PDT 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it....the problem is, that i import a project from subversion and its not e pure PHP Project. On PHP-Project is working fine. Yesterday i've imported the project first as PHP and not from Subversion ;)

Answer (score 6):

Add "Core API" to "PHP Language Library" in Eclipse PHP Project.

***Solution***:

- Right click on your Eclipse PHP Project -> Properties -> PHP Build Path.
- Click on "Add Folder…", and select the source folders to use (application, library, public, …), and then click on "Ok".
- Click on "Ok" to save changes.
- Close Eclipse.
- Go to project path.
- Open ".buildpath" with text editor (gedit, VIM, notepad, etc).
- Add next line after "`<buildpath>`" line:

  ***`<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>`***

**Example**:

*Before*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <buildpath>
            <buildpathentry kind="src" path="library"/>
            <buildpathentry kind="src" path="public"/>
            <buildpathentry kind="src" path="application"/>
         </buildpath>
```

*After*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <buildpath>
            <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
            <buildpathentry kind="src" path="library"/>
            <buildpathentry kind="src" path="public"/>
            <buildpathentry kind="src" path="application"/>
         </buildpath>
```

- Save file and exit!
- Open Eclipse.
- WORK!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it'll do, but maybe you can try adding the "PHP library" by hand :

- right click on your project
- properties
- PHP Include Path
- tab Libraries
- add external source folder
- navigate through your directories, to something like "eclipse/dropins/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core_2.0..../Resources/language/php5"
- add this directory

Does it help ?

(BTW, with this solution, you can get auto-completion / suggestions for PEAR libraries, for instance ; just add whatever library you're using to the PHP Include Path)

Else... Hu... Are you using a recent version of the JAVA VM ?

Comment: I solved it....the problem is, that i import a project from subversion and its not e pure PHP Project. On PHP-Project is working fine. Yesterday i've imported the project first as PHP and not from Subversion ;)

Answer (score 2):

Note that installing Dynamic Languages Toolkit breaks PHP autocomplete in the way none of the hints above work. It's great for ruby etc though.. I ended up installing separate PDT just for PHP alone.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, same problem this side, got it working by not choosing "enable Project Specific settings".

Answer (score 0):

Check the lib of your project. It may be that you have include two such jar files in which same class is available or say one class in code can be refrenced in two jar files. In such case also eclipse stops assisting code as it is totally confused.

Better way to check this is go to the file where assist is not working and comment all imports there, than add imports one by one and check at each import if code-assist is working or not.You can easily find the class with duplicate refrences.